# Pull random results from a database?

Tags: python-3.x

I have been coding in Python for a 2 months or so, but I mostly ask for help from a more experienced friend when I run in to these kinds of issues. I should also, before I begin, specify that I use Python *solely* for a personal project; any questions I ask will relate to each other through that.

With those two things out of the way, I have a database of weaponry items that I created using the following script, made in Python 3.X:

```
#Start by making a list of every material, weapontype, and upgrade.
Materials=("Unobtanium","IvorySilk","BoneLeather","CottonWood","Tin","Copper","Bronze","Gold","Cobalt","Tungsten")
WeaponTypes=("Knife","Sword","Greatsword","Polearm","Battlestaff","Claw","Cane","Wand","Talis","Slicer","Rod","Bow","Crossbow","Handbow","Pistol","Mechgun","Rifle","Shotgun")
Upgrades=("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10")

ForgeWInputs=[]
#Go through every material...
for m in Materials:
    #And in each material, go through  every weapontype...
    for w in WeaponTypes:
        #And in every weapontype, go through each upgrade...
        for u in Upgrades:
            ForgeWInputs.append((m,w,u))

#We now have a list "ForgeWInputs", which contains the 3-element list needed to
#Forge any weapon. For example...

MAT={}
MAT["UnobtaniumPD"]=0
MAT["UnobtaniumMD"]=0
MAT["UnobtaniumAC"]=0
MAT["UnobtaniumPR"]=0
MAT["UnobtaniumMR"]=0
MAT["UnobtaniumWT"]=0
MAT["UnobtaniumBuy"]=0
MAT["UnobtaniumSell"]=0

MAT["IvorySilkPD"]=0
MAT["IvorySilkMD"]=12
MAT["IvorySilkAC"]=3
MAT["IvorySilkPR"]=0
MAT["IvorySilkMR"]=3
MAT["IvorySilkWT"]=6
MAT["IvorySilkBuy"]=10
MAT["IvorySilkSell"]=5

MAT["CottonWoodPD"]=8
MAT["CottonWoodMD"]=8
MAT["CottonWoodAC"]=5
MAT["CottonWoodPR"]=0
MAT["CottonWoodMR"]=3
MAT["CottonWoodWT"]=6
MAT["CottonWoodBuy"]=14
MAT["CottonWoodSell"]=7

MAT["BoneLeatherPD"]=12
MAT["BoneLeatherMD"]=0
MAT["BoneLeatherAC"]=3
MAT["BoneLeatherPR"]=3
MAT["BoneLeatherMR"]=0
MAT["BoneLeatherWT"]=6
MAT["BoneLeatherBuy"]=10
MAT["BoneLeatherSell"]=5

MAT["TinPD"]=18
MAT["TinMD"]=6
MAT["TinAC"]=3
MAT["TinPR"]=5
MAT["TinMR"]=2
MAT["TinWT"]=12
MAT["TinBuy"]=20
MAT["TinSell"]=10

MAT["CopperPD"]=6
MAT["CopperMD"]=18
MAT["CopperAC"]=3
MAT["CopperPR"]=2
MAT["CopperMR"]=5
MAT["CopperWT"]=12
MAT["CopperBuy"]=20
MAT["CopperSell"]=10

MAT["BronzePD"]=10
MAT["BronzeMD"]=10
MAT["BronzeAC"]=5
MAT["BronzePR"]=3
MAT["BronzeMR"]=3
MAT["BronzeWT"]=15
MAT["BronzeBuy"]=30
MAT["BronzeSell"]=15

MAT["GoldPD"]=10
MAT["GoldMD"]=30
MAT["GoldAC"]=0
MAT["GoldPR"]=5
MAT["GoldMR"]=10
MAT["GoldWT"]=25
MAT["GoldBuy"]=50
MAT["GoldSell"]=25

MAT["CobaltPD"]=30
MAT["CobaltMD"]=10
MAT["CobaltAC"]=0
MAT["CobaltPR"]=10
MAT["CobaltMR"]=0
MAT["CobaltWT"]=25
MAT["CobaltBuy"]=50
MAT["CobaltSell"]=25

MAT["TungstenPD"]=20
MAT["TungstenMD"]=20
MAT["TungstenAC"]=0
MAT["TungstenPR"]=7
MAT["TungstenMR"]=7
MAT["TungstenWT"]=20
MAT["TungstenBuy"]=70
MAT["TungstenSell"]=35

WEP={}
WEP["KnifePD"]=0.5
WEP["KnifeMD"]=0.5
WEP["KnifeAC"]=1.25

WEP["SwordPD"]=1.0
WEP["SwordMD"]=1.0
WEP["SwordAC"]=1.0

WEP["GreatswordPD"]=1.67
WEP["GreatswordMD"]=0.67
WEP["GreatswordAC"]=0.5

WEP["PolearmPD"]=1.15
WEP["PolearmMD"]=1.15
WEP["PolearmAC"]=1.15

WEP["CanePD"]=1.15
WEP["CaneMD"]=1.15
WEP["CaneAC"]=0.7

WEP["ClawPD"]=1.1
WEP["ClawMD"]=1.1
WEP["ClawAC"]=0.8

WEP["BattlestaffPD"]=1.15
WEP["BattlestaffMD"]=1
WEP["BattlestaffAC"]=1.25

WEP["TalisPD"]=1.15
WEP["TalisMD"]=0.7
WEP["TalisAC"]=1.15

WEP["WandPD"]=0.0
WEP["WandMD"]=1
WEP["WandAC"]=1.33

WEP["RodPD"]=0.0
WEP["RodMD"]=1.67
WEP["RodAC"]=0.67

WEP["SlicerPD"]=0.67
WEP["SlicerMD"]=0.67
WEP["SlicerAC"]=0.67

WEP["BowPD"]=1.15
WEP["BowMD"]=1.15
WEP["BowAC"]=0.85

WEP["CrossbowPD"]=1.4
WEP["CrossbowMD"]=1.4
WEP["CrossbowAC"]=1

WEP["PistolPD"]=0.65
WEP["PistolMD"]=0.65
WEP["PistolAC"]=1.15

WEP["MechgunPD"]=0.2
WEP["MechgunMD"]=0.2
WEP["MechgunAC"]=1.5

WEP["ShotgunPD"]=1.3
WEP["ShotgunMD"]=1.3
WEP["ShotgunAC"]=0.4

WEP["RiflePD"]=0.75
WEP["RifleMD"]=0.75
WEP["RifleAC"]=1.75

WEP["HandbowPD"]=0.8
WEP["HandbowMD"]=0.8
WEP["HandbowAC"]=1.2

UP={}
UP["0PD"]=1.0
UP["1PD"]=1.1
UP["2PD"]=1.2
UP["3PD"]=1.3
UP["4PD"]=1.4
UP["5PD"]=1.5
UP["6PD"]=1.6
UP["7PD"]=1.7
UP["8PD"]=1.8
UP["9PD"]=1.9
UP["10PD"]=2.0

UP["0MD"]=1.0
UP["1MD"]=1.1
UP["2MD"]=1.2
UP["3MD"]=1.3
UP["4MD"]=1.4
UP["5MD"]=1.5
UP["6MD"]=1.6
UP["7MD"]=1.7
UP["8MD"]=1.8
UP["9MD"]=1.9
UP["10MD"]=2.0

UP["0AC"]=1.0
UP["1AC"]=1.1
UP["2AC"]=1.2
UP["3AC"]=1.3
UP["4AC"]=1.4
UP["5AC"]=1.5
UP["6AC"]=1.6
UP["7AC"]=1.7
UP["8AC"]=1.8
UP["9AC"]=1.9
UP["10AC"]=2.0

UP["0PR"]=1.0
UP["1PR"]=1.1
UP["2PR"]=1.2
UP["3PR"]=1.3
UP["4PR"]=1.4
UP["5PR"]=1.5
UP["6PR"]=1.6
UP["7PR"]=1.7
UP["8PR"]=1.8
UP["9PR"]=1.9
UP["10PR"]=2.0

UP["0MR"]=1.0
UP["1MR"]=1.1
UP["2MR"]=1.2
UP["3MR"]=1.3
UP["4MR"]=1.4
UP["5MR"]=1.5
UP["6MR"]=1.6
UP["7MR"]=1.7
UP["8MR"]=1.8
UP["9MR"]=1.9
UP["10MR"]=2.0

UP["0WT"]=1.0
UP["1WT"]=0.95
UP["2WT"]=0.9
UP["3WT"]=0.85
UP["4WT"]=0.8
UP["5WT"]=0.75
UP["6WT"]=0.7
UP["7WT"]=0.65
UP["8WT"]=0.6
UP["9WT"]=0.55
UP["10WT"]=0.5

def ForgeW(Material,WeaponType,UpgradeLevel):
    """The ForgeW function Forges a Weapon from its base components into a lethal tool."""

    #Get the appropriate material stats...
    OrePD=MAT[Material+"PD"]
    OreMD=MAT[Material+"MD"]
    OreAC=MAT[Material+"AC"]

    #And weapon type stats...
    SmithPD=WEP[WeaponType+"PD"]
    SmithMD=WEP[WeaponType+"MD"]
    SmithAC=WEP[WeaponType+"AC"]

    #And apply the upgrade...
    UpgradePD=UP[UpgradeLevel+"PD"]
    UpgradeMD=UP[UpgradeLevel+"MD"]
    UpgradeAC=UP[UpgradeLevel+"AC"]

    #Then, add them all together.   
    ProductPD=(OrePD*SmithPD)*UpgradePD
    ProductMD=(OreMD*SmithMD)*UpgradeMD
    ProductAC=(OreAC*SmithAC)*UpgradeAC

    return(ProductPD,ProductMD,ProductAC)

#Recall that ForgeW simply needs its three inputs, which we have a list of. So, let's make our
#database of weapon information.
OmniWeapData={}

#Go through every set of inputs we have...
for Inputs in ForgeWInputs:
    #And create a key in the dictionary by combining their three names. Then, set that
    #key equal to whatever ForgeW returns when those three inputs are put in.
    OmniWeapData[Inputs[0]+Inputs[1]+Inputs[2]] = ForgeW(Inputs[0],Inputs[1],Inputs[2])
```

I would like to refer to the database created by this code and pull out weapons at random, and frankly I have no idea how. As an example of what I would like to do...

Well, hum. The code in question should spit out a certain number of results based on the complete products of the ForgeW function - if I specify, either within the code or through an input, that I would like 3 outputs, it might output a GoldKnife0, a TinPolearm5, and a CobaltGreatsword10. If I were to run the code again, it should dispense new equipment - not the same three every time.

I apologize if this is too much or too little data - it's my first time asking a question here.

Answer (score 1):

"Take this... it may help you on your quest."

There is a library called random with a method called choice().
e.g.

```
import random
random.choice([1,2,3])
>>> 2
```

It sounds like you need one item from Materials, one item from WeaponTypes, and one from Upgrades.

Also, rarely is there ever a need for a triple nested FOR statement.  This should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I figured out what I need to do~!